# Markup parser failing

Tags: antlr, antlr3, parser-generator

For a markup language I'm trying to parse, I decided to give parser generation a try with ANTLR. I'm new to the field, and I'm messing something up.

My grammar is

```
grammar Test;
DIGIT   :   ('0'..'9');
LETTER  :   ('A'..'Z');
SLASH   :   '/'; 
restriction
    :   ('E' ap)
    |   ('L' ap)
    |   'N';
ap  :   LETTER LETTER LETTER;
car :   LETTER LETTER;
fnum    :   DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT? LETTER?;
flt :   car fnum?;
message :   'A' (SLASH flt)? (SLASH restriction)?;
```

which does exactly what I want, when I give it an input string `A/KK543/EPOS`. When I give it `A/KL543/EPOS` however, it fails (`MismatchedTokenException(9!=5)`). It seems like some sort of conflict; it wants to generate `restriction` on the first L, so it seems I'm doing something wrong in the language definition, but I can't properly find out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the input `"A/KK543/EPOS"`, the following tokens are created:

```
'A'        'A'
SLASH      '/'
LETTER     'K'
LETTER     'K'
DIGIT      '5'
DIGIT      '4'
DIGIT      '3'
SLASH      '/'
'E'        'E'
LETTER     'P'
LETTER     'O'
LETTER     'S'
```

But for the input `"A/KL543/EPOS"`, these are created:

```
'A'        'A'
SLASH      '/'
LETTER     'K'
'L'        'L'
DIGIT      '5'
DIGIT      '4'
DIGIT      '3'
SLASH      '/'
'E'        'E'
LETTER     'P'
LETTER     'O'
LETTER     'S'
```

As you can see, the char `'L'` does *not* get tokenized as a `LETTER`. For the literal tokens `'A'`, `'E'`, `'L'` and `'N'` inside your parser rules, ANTLR (automatically) creates separate lexer rules that are place before all other lexer rules. This causes your lexer to look like this behind the scenes:

```
A      : 'A';
E      : 'E';
L      : 'L';
N      : 'N';
DIGIT  : '0'..'9';
LETTER : 'A'..'Z';
SLASH  : '/';
```

Therefor, any single `'A'`, `'E'`, `'L'` and `'N'` will never become a `LETTER` token. This is simply how ANTLR works. If you want to match them as letters, you'll need to create a parser rule `letter` and let *it* match these tokens too. Something like this:

```
message
 : A (SLASH flt)? (SLASH restriction)?
 ;

flt
 : car fnum?
 ;

fnum
 : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT? letter?
 ;

restriction
 : E ap
 | L ap
 | N
 ;

ap
 : letter letter letter
 ;

car
 : letter letter
 ;

letter
 : A
 | E
 | L
 | N
 | LETTER
 ;

A      : 'A';
E      : 'E';
L      : 'L';
N      : 'N';
DIGIT  : '0'..'9';
LETTER : 'A'..'Z';
SLASH  : '/';
```

which will parse the input `"A/KL543/EPOS"` like this:

[image]